# liferay portal canvas resize

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, liferay

I am using three.js to embed webgl into a liferay portlet. I would like to be able to have the renderer resize the image (canvas element) when I make changes to the page layout that effect the portlet size. So basically whenever the portlet resizes I want to be able to resize the canvas through the three.js calls. Three.js has a renderer object through which I can set size. The problem is getting the width of the portlet. Is there a way to capture a redraw event and grab the portlet width to be used to resize a canvas element?

Thanks

Comment: did you try using width:auto ?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to both, the `portletMoved` and `updatedLayout` events on Liferay.

```
Liferay.on('portletMoved', function(event) {
    var portlet = event.portlet;

    var newWidth = portlet.width(),
        newHeight = portlet.height();

    [...]
});

Liferay.on('updatedLayout', function(event) {
    // Assuming you have Alloy on your script, you can use A.one to get the
    // portlet node. Otherwise, you could use document.getElementById
    var portlet = A.one('#' + portletId);

    var newWidth = portlet.width(),
        newHeight = portlet.height();

    [...]
});
```

Comment: I tried the first suggested event in my javascript on my portlet jsp. I modified it to just put up an alert("portlet moved") when the event occurred. This did not work. I changed the name of the event to 'allPortletsReady' and the event was caught and the alert posted. Where can I find a list of valid event names that liferay uses?